# kafka binder custom serializer

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

In spring cloud stream kafka we can define custom key or value deserializer via configuration:

```
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.configuration.value.deserializer: com.example.demo.serde.CustomDeserializer
```

Desirializer class:

```
package com.example.demo.serde;

import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Deserializer;

public class CustomDeserializer implements Deserializer<String> {

    @Override
    public String deserialize(String s, byte[] bytes) {
        return "Custom deserialization";
    }
}
```

It's works fine, but how I can define custom kafka serializer of deserializer via Spring java configuration like this:

```
@Configuration
public class KafkaConfig {

    @Bean
    public Deserializer<String> customDeserializer() {
        return new CustomDeserializer();
    }

}
```

How to define custom serializer or deserializer bean via java configuration in spring cloud stream?

Comment: Why would you need to have it be a bean?

Comment: Sometimes I need to pass some params to deserializer form spring config like this:

@Bean
    public Deserializer<String> customDeserializer(@Value("${some.param}") String param) {
        return new CustomDeserializer(String param);
    }

Comment: Serializers don't take constructor parameters, they have their own configure method... You can look at the Confluent Avro serializers as an example, and you just pass `value.derserializer.prop` in the spring properties

Comment: I can pass params form configuration through Serializer#configure method. But with spring kafka we can configure KafkaTemplate and Serilalizer and Deserializer with constructor params via java config. Does it posible to do with same way using spring cloud stream?

Comment: No; Spring Cloud Stream does not support injecting (de)Serializer objects into the consumer or producer factory, only configuring them via properties and the `configure()` method.